# Convert natural year to hydrological year time series Rasterbrick R

Tags: r, maps, time-series, raster

Given a `rasterbrick` with natural years (`Jan-Dec`), how can one convert it to have hydrological years (starting on the `1st October and ending on the following 30th September`)? Something similar (but not exact) to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073881/hydrological-year-time-series).

**Sample data:**

```
     nl <- 768
     s <- brick(nrows = 510,  ncols = 1068,
                   xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -90, ymx = 90,
                   crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84",
                   nl = nl,values=TRUE)
        dates <- seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by = "month")
        s <- setZ(s, dates)
vals <- 1:ncell(s)
s[]=vals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [wrote a function](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/flowdurr/blob/master/dev/R/to_wateryear.R) for this a while ago.

```
to_wateryear <- function(thedate){
  thedate = as.Date(thedate)
  year = as.integer(substr(thedate, 1, 4))
  cutoff =  cutoff = as.Date(paste(year, '-10-01', sep=''))
  return(ifelse(thedate < cutoff, 
           year*1000 + thedate - as.Date(paste(year - 1, '-09-30', sep='')),
           (year + 1)*1000 + thedate - as.Date(paste(year, '-09-30', sep=''))))
}
```

Examples:

```
to_wateryear(as.Date(Sys.time()))
to_wateryear('2013-10-01')
# leap year behavior
to_wateryear('2012-09-30')
to_wateryear('2013-09-30')
to_wateryear('2012-02-29')
to_wateryear('2013-03-31')
```

**EDIT** From your comments it sounds like what you actually want is to **split** your rasterbrick by water year, rather than representing dates in terms of hydrologic year.

```
library(raster)
nl <- 768
s <- brick(nrows = 510,  ncols = 1068, 
  xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -90, ymx = 90,
  crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84",
  nl = nl,values=TRUE)

dates <- seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by = "month")
# use water year
s <- setZ(s, to_wateryear(dates))
vals <- 1:ncell(s)
s[]=vals

# split by water year
hyears = unique(getZ(s) %/% 1000)
res = vector("list", length(hyears))
for(i in 1:length(hyears))
  res[[i]] = s[[which(getZ(s) %/% 1000 == hyears[i])]]
names(res) = paste0("HY", hyears)
```

Comment: This could be very helpful. Can you test it on my `rasterbrick,s`?

Comment: I did provide sample data above. I will try it when I get to my computer. However, pls try and let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the following but got numbers instead of dates: `s <- setZ(s, to_wateryear(dates))`

Comment: Yes... How do you want to represent dates wrt water year? Perhaps you should add an example of the output you are expecting.

Comment: Something like this but on a rasterbrick `https://gist.github.com/cvitolo/e2ec4887f376e3b7d912`

Comment: Thanks for these updates. It is getting closer. `res` in your solution is a large `list` but I want a single `rasterbrick` `s` with `**data and years**` formatted as hydrologic years. The `time` attribute in `s` should be formated as in `as.Date` `time        : 1950-10-01, 2013-09-31 (min, max)`

Comment: Sounds like you want a new `datetime` class. Good luck!